# Whats the significance of $g^{-1}$ (the inverse metric) appearing in tangential projection?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tensors

Let $M \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^n,g_E)$ be an embedded submanifold, with the embedding $F : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$. It is well known (c.f. Lee, doCarmo) that the covariant derivative on $M$ with respect to the induced metric $g = F^* g_E$ ($g_E$ being the Euclidean metric $\delta_{ij}$),
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$$ \nabla_X Y = \pi^{\top} ( \tilde \nabla_{\tilde X} \tilde Y) $$
where $\nabla, \tilde \nabla$ are the covariant derivatives on $M,\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively, and $\pi^\top$ is the tangential projection onto $T_p M$. In local coordinates, since the columns of the pushforward $dF_p$ produce a basis for the tangent space $T_p M \subseteq  T_{f(p)} \R$, we can write this projection $\pi^\top$ using the [orthogonal projector formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas), if we let $\tilde v = \tilde \nabla_{\tilde X} \tilde Y$,
$$ \pi^{\top} \tilde v = dF_p [dF_p^T dF_p]^{-1} dF_p^T \tilde v$$
The part in square brackets $[dF_p^T dF_p]$, is nothing more than the coordinate expression of $F^* g_E$ evaluated at $p$. The inverse then corresponds to the inverse (dual) metric $(F^* g_E)^{-1}$.

My question is, *what is the inverse metric doing in the projection formula?*  It seems possible there is an interpretation of its role here as "raising an index", since the output of $dF_p^T = dF_p^*$ is a covector — but $\tilde v$ is definitely a vector so the expression fails to type check that way.

Comment: Forget manifolds and tensors. This is just a matter of understanding the linear algebra of orthogonal projection onto the column space of a matrix of maximal rank.

Comment: I believe I understand the linear algebra for a single tangent space. But when it comes to the bundle, I was hoping the appearance of $g^{-1}$ might imply something beyond merely "it works out this way in coordinates at one point"